# how can I take starting two character of a string

Tags: php

how can I take starting two character of a string regardless the string lenght.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `substr()`

```
$string = substr("something", 0, 2);
```

Comment: You can also access parts of a string as an array: `$string[0]` and `$string[1]` are its first two characters.

Comment: but only if the original string is two characters or longer. Do this to be safe:
$string = strlen($str) > 2 ? substr($str, 0, 2) : $str; (strip only if it's longer than 2 chars)

Comment: And if you are using UTF8 or other multibyte encoding, use `mb_substr()`